# External application.properties file overriding values in Spring Boot 2.2.1

Tags: spring-boot

I have seen many questions in regards to Spring Boot external configuration, in specific, externalizing a `application.properties` file, but didn't find a specific answer on whether property values from externalized application.properties files should be *merged* or the whole .properties file on the classpath should be *overridden* with the external one.

After recent app upgrade to Spring Boot 2.2.1-RELEASE version, there was a need to enable bean overriding with `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` property, which is set in the application.properties file on the classpath. Since we want to use an external application.properties file, I created one(same name) without the aforementioned property and loaded it with the following property in IntelliJ:

`java -jar appName.jar --spring.config.location="C:\Users\User\Downloads\application.properties"`

The error came up as though the external props file completely overrode the classpath file, without looking for the mentioned property in the classpath file and using the missing property from the classpath `application.properties`:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'userRepository' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

After adding the bean overriding property to the external application.properties file, but **removing it from the classpath one**, error is gone.

In Spring docs, it is clearly stated that :

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is designed to allow sensible **overriding of values**. Properties are considered in the following order:
>
> > ...
> >
> > > 14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> > > 15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).

After testing it out with IntelliJ and a packaged jar, both method exhibit the same: seems like the whole file is being overridden and values are not merged, but only loaded from the externalized properties file. My questions is, is this the expected behavior or am I missing out on something ?

EDIT: tested the behavior with jar

Comment: That is only when Spring Boot detects the files, however by specifying a full path to a file with `spring.config.location` this behavior doesn't apply and only that file will be loaded. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files. Instead use `spring.config.additional-locations` as a property and specify the directory only NOT the fulll file. It will be loaded and the given rules will then apply.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, it makes sense. For that, I created a directory C:\Users\<user>\custom-config\, in which I placed the application.properties file with the missing property to be picked up by the classpath file. Added the program argument in IntelliJ as ".. --spring.config.additional-location=file:C:\Users\<user>\custom-config\", but the property is not loaded from the classpath file (error persists). Is there a problem with the path string, could you maybe give me an example of a valid file system path ?

Comment: EDIT: it is working now, there were some unrelated problems with build. Thank you for the help!